# All the elements of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on $\Omega$ generated by the sets $A$ and $B$

Tags: probability

> Let $\Omega := \{1, 2, \ldots, 6\}$, so that $A :=\{1, 3\}$, $B:=\{1,4,5\}$ are subsets of $\Omega$. List all the elements of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on $\Omega$ generated by the sets $A$ and $B$. How many elements are there in $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to deal with the problem

Comment: $\mathcal F$ has to include $\Omega, \emptyset, A, B$ and every other subset of $\Omega$ that can be obtained by taking unions and complements of these. Can you follow?

Comment: would you mind show me the complete answer?please

Answer (score 1):

You have $\mathcal F = \{\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i : I\subset\{1,2,3,4\} \}$ with

\begin{align}
A_1&:=\{1\}=(\{1,3\}^c\cup \{1,4,5\}^c)^c,\\
A_2&:=\{3\}=(\{1,3\}^c\cup \{1,4,5\})^c,\\
A_3&:=\{4,5\}=(\{1,3\}\cup \{1,4,5\}^c)^c,\\
A_4&:=\{2,6\}=(\{1,3\}\cup \{1,4,5\})^c.
\end{align}

Hence, $\mathcal F$ contains $2^4=16$ elements.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Do you understand why this is correct?